# Drop shadow filter offsets border in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

If you use Shadow filters in IE8 on a DIV, the DIV's contents will be offset by the shadow. If you give that DIV a border, this leads to weird behaviour. This is how it looks

[image]

The whole contents and the shadow go out of bounds of the div, having an offset to the border. Is there any way to correct this, or even to fake-correct this, at least getting the border back in position?

Comment: Also, what version of IE do you have? My IE9 doesn't show this problem. P.s. what does 'Shadow()' indicate? Parentheses aren't exactly CSS code.

Comment: Try dropping the shadow filter, and switching to [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). It can emulate `box-shadow`, which is I assume what you're trying to emulate in IE8 with that filter.

Comment: @KeesSonnema https://gist.github.com/2994569

Comment: @poepje I'm using IE 8. The shadow() thing is a proprietary IE CSS property

Comment: @thirtydot CSS3PIE seems great! Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just specify all the shadow direction instead of typing a new line of code for other directions? i don't know if this is possible

Comment: @Lukas Doesn't IE8 support the normal CSS3 box-shadow property, like this? `-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}`

Comment: @poepje: No. http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

Comment: @thirtydot That's why I mentioned `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow` as well, besides the basic `box-shadow`. Nothing about those is said on the page you linked to.

Comment: @poepje: What are you smoking? First of all, that page does mention `-webkit-` and `-moz-` (look carefully and use logic). Secondly, you really think that **IE8** might support `-moz-box-shadow` or `-webkit-box-shadow`?  Read up on vendor prefixes.